# MySQL подключение

Tags: python, mysql

На сервере `CentOS 7` есть бд `MySQL`, также установлен `ssh` вход.

Если я хочу подключиться к бд через `Python` с сервера на котором и стоит сама бд мне нужно использовать просто `pymysql.connect` или нужно открывать `ssh`?

Comment: ssh  обычно используют для управления сервером, если нужно запустить скрипт, то да нужно подключиться по ssh к серверу и запустить скрипт, если кто-то запустит скрипт, то ssh не нужен.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что для подключения к базе данных с самого сервера на котором эта база данных находится нужно ли ssh или можно без?

Comment: Я именно это имел в виду, если вы имеете доступ к терминалу сервера (можете ввести команду с клавиатуры сервера) то ssh не нужен, если вы находитесь далеко, не можете использовать клавиатуру сервера, то подключаетесь по ssh  и используете свою клавиатуру для управления сервером.